# How to finish edges of drywall between exposed wall studs

Tags: walls

I want to leave wall studs in my beach cottage exposed.  My first choice for in between is drywall panels.

How do I handle the joints where the drywall will butt up against studs?  Do I tape and sand them--or is there some alternative?

Before deciding on this look, we insulated walls (rigid insulation) from the inside.  I was planning to address this issue by attaching the drywall to a small frame to be added inside the studs.

Comments or advice?

Comment: If its just the look you're going for I'd be inclined to fake it by attaching some 1.5"x0.5" wood strips vertically onto the finished drywall. Were you thinking of painting the exposed studs the same color as the wall or would you stain/poly them or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Why not get some lauan plywood and use that instead? I think it would be easier and cheaper. If you're leaving the studs exposed then the wall must not be a firewall of any sort so you should be okay to use another type of wood. I think you'll end up with much better seems butting up to the sides of your studs. You can also paint it if you desire. If you wanted the studs to be a different color/stain I might do those first then put up your inside material.

Comment: "the wall must not be a firewall of any sort" +1

Answer (score 1):

A drywall J-bead or tear-away bead will give a clean look when butting drywall against wood or brick.